# ADO.NET Entity Framework with OLE DB SQLServer2000 Data Source

Tags: ado.net, frameworks, entity

Same as Title.
Has anyone found a way to make the ADO.NET Entity Framework work with OLE DB or ODBC data sources? Specifically, I need to work with an SqlServer2000.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 and EF4 do no longer support SQL Server 2000 - are you using VS2010??

Check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896309.aspx

> Note
>
> Starting with Visual Studio 2010, the
>   ADO.NET Entity Data Model Tools do not
>   support SQL Server 2000.

Comment: But will it still work using code first? Because that is what I am working with right now.